# Why do I get a custom audience successful response without actual success?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, hash, facebook-ads-api

I am developing an App with the Facebook Custom Audiences API and my match rate is 0% despite a successful response message. I go through each step the same way it is in their documents but none ever match.

First I create the audience through the API, and then add I add a description with the API, both of those work. I even get a successful response when I submit array of email addresses: 
    {"audience_id":"XXX","num_received":460,"num_invalid_entries":0,"invalid_entry_samples":[]}"

But when I look at the audience in facebook, the audience has the error message "Not ready audience too small." I figured this must be an issue with my hashing steps, which I had copied directly from their documentation. I submitted their example email "mary@example.com" into my app

Facebook example hash: f1904cf1a9d73a55fa5de0ac823c4403ded71afd4c3248d00bdcd0866552bb79

My app's hash value  : f1904cf1a9d73a55fa5de0ac823c4403ded71afd4c3248d00bdcd0866552bb79

I even entered the test email address into my app multiple times, so position in the array has nothing to do with the hashing.

My final test was to upload the list manually, to see if there are in fact zero matches. There were 100 matches almost immediately. what gives?

Is there any reason for me to get a successful response besides issues with the hashing?

Comment: Let me clear this up..You want to get a successful response from something which did not truly succeed?

Comment: I get a successful response, however I did not succeed. haha I worded the question wrong

Comment: can you give an example of your payload to add users to the audience? You can just include the sample hash rather than actual email address hashes.

Comment: i changed nothing but it somehow started working. that change coincided with a change in the ui on facebook, so perhaps it was on their end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the issue was Facebook returning a "success" message because it received the hashed values successfully and can process those hashes without issue. This doesn't imply that the matching is done on Facebook's end or that they got matches.

Rather than have your connection wait while it processes your hashes, Facebook will just make sure everything's OK, return that success message, and then process the hashes offline. This means it could take some time for the hashes to be matched to Facebook users. Oftentimes it's pretty quick, but I've seen it take hours sometimes.

Facebook's [audience management API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/custom-audience-targeting/v2.4#add) states that it could take up to an hour to add someone to an audience. That applies to each batch of hashes you're sending (since each batch is limited to 10,000 hashes).

Comment: accepted as correct answer, thanks for the well documented response